# REACT: Fetch returns response as not ok but Network tab shows data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and when I am trying to fetch the json response into UI I am getting error, even though the network tab shows the json response.

Please help me in resolving this.

**Code-**

```js
useEffect(() =>    {
        console.log('Inside UseEffect');
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/hello`
            ,{ mode: 'no-cors', method: 'GET'    })
            .then((response) => {
                if(!response.ok) throw new Error(`This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`);
                else return response.json();
            })
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({
                    teamList: json});
                console.log(this.state.teamList);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, [] )
```

**Network tab response looks like-**

[{"id":1,"title":"Team1"},{"id":2,"title":"Team2"},{"id":3,"title":"Team3"},{"id":4,"title":"Team4"},{"id":5,"title":"Team5"},{"id":6,"title":"Team6"}]

***And the Console tab has below output-***

Inside UseEffect

Error: This is an HTTP error: The status is 0

Comment: @BeHappy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok

Comment: This `response.status` equal to `0` is unsettling

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 if(!response.ok) throw new Error(`This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`);
 else return response.json();
```

in the then anonymous function do `console.log({response})`

You can then see in the console what the object looks like and interrupt how to extract the data from it.

`response.ok` is most likely undefined